# NetworkMember trigger not executing when reputation points increase

Tags: trigger, chatter, reputation

I'm trying to create a POC for reputation levels / capturing changes in a trigger. I've seen various Salesforce docs that mention this is possible with `NetworkMember` triggers:

1. [NetworkMember object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm). Scroll to **Usage** section, highlighted in yellow box.
2. [Chatter API sample code](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_recog_badges_via_api.htm&type=0). Scroll to **Assign a Recognition Badge When a Member Reaches a Number of Reputation Points** section.

I've verified reputation points are increasing after a post, comment, like, etc. but for some reason the `NetworkMember` trigger is not invoked. No debug logs are created.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**NetworkMemberTrigger.trigger**

```
trigger NetworkMemberTrigger on NetworkMember (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {
    NetworkMemberTriggerHandler.handleTrigger(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.operationType);
}
```

**NetworkMemberTriggerHandler.cls**

```
public with sharing class NetworkMemberTriggerHandler {
    public static void handleTrigger(List<NetworkMember> newRecords, Map<Id, NetworkMember> oldMap, System.TriggerOperation triggerEvent) {
        switch on triggerEvent {
            when BEFORE_INSERT { handleBeforeInsert(newRecords); }
            when AFTER_INSERT  { handleAfterInsert(newRecords); }
            when BEFORE_UPDATE { handleBeforeUpdate(newRecords, oldMap); }
            when AFTER_UPDATE  { handleAfterUpdate(newRecords, oldMap); }
        }
    }

    public static void handleBeforeInsert(List<NetworkMember> newRecords) {
        System.debug('============ NETWORK MEMBER - BEFORE INSERT ===========');
    }

    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<NetworkMember> newRecords) {
        System.debug('============ NETWORK MEMBER - AFTER INSERT ===========');
    }

    public static void handleBeforeUpdate(List<NetworkMember> newRecords, Map<Id, NetworkMember> oldMap) {
        System.debug('============ NETWORK MEMBER - BEFORE UPDATE ===========');
    }

    public static void handleAfterUpdate(List<NetworkMember> newRecords, Map<Id, NetworkMember> oldMap) {
        System.debug('============ NETWORK MEMBER - AFTER UPDATE ===========');
        for(NetworkMember member : newRecords) {
            System.debug('Reputation Points: ' + member.ReputationPoints);
            System.debug('Last Chatter Activity Date: ' + member.LastChatterActivityDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just double-checking the basics: your trigger is Active in the org, right? If you persist a change to an sObject rather than executing a debug log, do you get any evidence that the trigger is running?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, trigger is active. When I change `ReputationPoints` in Query Editor it does invoke the `NetworkMember` trigger. But if I ask a question or receive an upvote within my site/Chatter, the reputation increases but the trigger is not invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view logs for your NetworkMember trigger by adding a debug log on Automated Process.

Navigate to Setup > Debug Logs. Click New under User Trace Flags. For "Traced Entity Type", select "Automated Process".

Figured this out by inserting an Account inside the NetworkMember trigger. The "user" that was creating those Accounts was the Automated Process.

Comment: This is a huge help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this scenario in my org and then verified our Salesforce internal logs that the trigger on NetworkMember is being fired and there are no errors in this process.

This behavior is working as designed. When the trigger is fired the debug logs are generated in the context of the Automated process.

Typically, triggers run in the context of the running user but certain operations may need to be evaluated in the context of Automated Process users.

Some examples are Transaction Security Policies, [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_debug_autoproc.htm), event processes, and resumed flow interviews, and more.
Also see similar [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173044/how-do-i-see-debug-logs-for-platform-event-triggers-in-salesforce).

I have documented this information so it can help others in the future.

KnowledgeArticle link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000358278&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Frustrating I couldn't find this knowledge article - but helpful nonetheless.